# Get number from an url in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have the following url : `http:example.com/country/France/45`.
With the pattern `http:example.com/country/name/**NUMBER**(?$_GET possibly)`.

How can I extract the number with a regex (or something else then regex) ?

Comment: \/country\/.*\/([0-9]+) try this with preg_match_all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regexp:

```
$str = 'http:example.com/country/France/45';
preg_match('/http:example\.com\/country\/(?P<name>\w+)\/(?P<id>\d+)/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches); // return array("name"=>"France", "id" => 45);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo $last = substr(strrchr($url, "/"), 1 );
```

`strrchr()` will give last occurence of the `/` character and then `substr()` gives string after it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$url = 'http:example.com/country/France/45';
$id  = end(explode('/',trim($url,'/')));
```

Simple isn't ?

The usage of `trim ()` is to remove trailing `\`

Answer (score 1):

use something like this

```
    $url = "http://example.com/country/France/45";
    $parts = explode('/', $url);
    $number = $parts[count($parts) - 1];
```

and if you have GET variable at the end, you can explode further like this

```
    $number = explode('?', $number);
    $number = $number[0];
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score -2):

Use `explode()`:

```
$parts = explode('/', $url);
$number = $parts[count($parts)-1];
```

Comment: This will fail, if there is no get parameter and the url doesn't end with a `/`!

Comment: I think you want to say $number = $parts[count($parts)-1]

Answer (score -2):

the get command for `php` is `$_GET` so to show to number do

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo $_GET["eg"];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

with a URL of `http:example.com/country/name/?eg=**NUMBER**`